# How to get SetMultiline(true) to honor wrapping of text

Tags: itext7

I'm attempting to add form fields to an existing PDF in a .NET 7.0.0 app using iText7 7.2.4 on Mac and I cannot get multiline text fields to honor wrapping without doing a weird hack.

The following code illustrates the issue:

```
using iText.Forms;
using iText.Forms.Fields;
using iText.IO.Font.Constants;
using iText.Kernel.Colors;
using iText.Kernel.Font;
using iText.Kernel.Geom;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;

// Create a new PDF document
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("my_document.pdf"));

// Create a page and add it to the document
PdfPage page = pdf.AddNewPage();

// Create an AcroForm and add it to the document
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);

// Create a multiline text field that should wrap but does not.
PdfTextFormField nonWrapping = PdfFormField.CreateText
    (pdf,
    new Rectangle(25, 727, 100, 100),
    "multiline-field-without-wrapping",
    String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("Hello World ", 10)),
    PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA),
    9.0F);

nonWrapping.SetMultiline(true);
form.AddField(nonWrapping);


 // Create a multiline text field that DOES wrap but 
// only because we set a background color.
PdfTextFormField wrapping = PdfFormField.CreateText
    (pdf,
    new Rectangle(150, 727, 100, 100),
    "multiline-field-with-wrapping",
    String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("Hello World ", 10)),
    PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA),
    9.0F);

wrapping.SetMultiline(true);
wrapping.SetBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(0.9F, 0.9F, 0.99F));
form.AddField(wrapping);

// Close the document
pdf.Close();
```

It will result in a PDF that looks like this in Preview:

[image: Wrapping Issue Example]

The only way I can get wrapping to work is by including background color. I don't want to do this but it's the only thing that works.

If I could set the opacity of the background color, that might also be acceptable but so far, I've been unable to find anything in the code or docs that would support this.

Comment: Have you tried setting the value of the field _after_ setting `Multiline` to `true`?

Comment: Well damn. I just relied on the constructor to set the value but if I ALSO set the value after calling SetMultiline(true), it works as I would have hoped without needing to set a background color. I'm guessing that calling SetBackgroundColor() did some kind of evaluation of the field just as SetMultiline() does.


Thanks for making me feel dumb but also making me so damn happy that I don't need to use a background color.

Comment: Well, one must be aware that the value is stored in two forms in the PDF: It is stored as the plain value (for automatic form content retrieval) and as a formatted appearance used for displaying the value in a viewer. When you set the value in the constructor, the formatted appearance is created using the formatting given in the constructor, i.e. without *Multiline*. Apparently setting the *Multiline* property does not trigger a recreation of that formatted appearance but both setting the background color and setting the value do trigger it. This is a bit inconsequential of the API.